# Is it possible to make a variable in JSS like Sass

Tags: css, material-ui, themes, jss

I am working on a React project. For styling I am using Material-ui with JSS. In Sass we can create variable and use it later like this `$color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 255)`. 
I want to use variable like Sass in JSS. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a javascript variable

```
const color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255, 255)';

const style = {
    button: {
        color: color
    },
};
```